# I can't seem to access chrome sync storage in my Google Chrome theme extension script

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-web-store, google-chrome-storage

I have an existing theme which I'm updating to manifest v3. Everything is fine with that process but I decided to dig deeper and offer a users a couple of options for the theme. I now have an options.html and did have an options.js but had to embed that in the html file as I couldn't get it to use the external script.

I have 95% of this all working (style, click events all firing correctly and a couple of variables I need to save to some local storage (or ideally using `chrome.storage.local.set()` and `chrome.storage.local.get()`.

Every time I try to use these I keep getting an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')` I've tied `local` `sync` and `session` on both `get` and `set` but I always end up with this error. I've also tried just `storage.local` `Uncaught ReferenceError: storage is not defined`. Not sure if it's my javascript, how I am running my extension locally, the limitations of running it local or something else.

manifest.json

```json
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "name of theme",
    "description": "description of theme",
    "theme": {
        "images": {
            "theme_ntp_background": "images/main.png"
        },
        "colors": {
            "bookmark_text": [ 0, 128, 0 ],
            "ntp_text": [ 128, 0, 0 ],
            "tab_background_text": [ 0, 0, 128 ],
            "tab_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
            "toolbar": [ 210, 212, 202 ]
        },
        "tints" : {
            "buttons" : [0.33, 0.5, 0.47]
        },
        "properties" : {
            "ntp_background_alignment" : "top"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ],
    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html",
        "open_in_tab": false
    },
    "web_accessible_resources":[
        "options.js",
        "images/option-resolution-1.jpg",
        "images/option-resolution-2.jpg",
        "images/option-resolution-3.jpg",
        "images/option-style-1.jpg",
        "images/option-style-2.jpg",
        "images/option-style-3.jpg"
    ]
}
```

My options.html

```html
<html>

<!--
...
-->

<script>
const tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('tile');
let style = 1;
let res = 3;

//...
const restoreOptions = () => {
    console.log('loaded restore');
    console.log('style: ' + style);
    console.log('res: ' + res);
    chrome.storage.sync.get(
       { style: 1, res: 1 },
       (items) => {
        style = items.style;
        res = items.res;
        }
    );
};


//onload
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restoreOptions);
</script>
</html>
```

I'm even just trying this to try and get it to work.

```js
chrome.storage.local.set({ key: "value" }).then(() => {
        console.log("Value was set");
    });
```

```
console.dir(storage); //Uncaught ReferenceError: storage is not defined
console.dir(storage.local); //Uncaught ReferenceError: storage is not defined
console.dir(chrome); //{csi, loadtimes, Object}
console.dir(chrome.storage); //undefined
console.dir(chrome.storage.local); //options.html:179 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')
```

The way I'm loading my extension is through chrome://extensions/ page with "development mode" on, I'm then selecting "Load unpacked" and choosing my directory where I have my files.

I then have to navigate (annoyingly) to a new tab, select the pencil then click "Edit the current theme you have installed" which sends me to a page which isn't available but it gives me the unique id of the extension. I can then just simply go to chrome-extension://{myfunnylongidthatseemstostaystaticanyway}/options.html

Comment: Themes can't use chrome API.